# Passing multiple functions to another function within a vector in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to write a solver for coupled ordinary differential equations, which will require me to pass multiple functions to the solver function.  The idea is that a user can write their coupled ODE functions in a main file, call the framework header file and pass their functions to the framework to solve the ODE.

In some cases there may just be two functions, in others there could be three, four, or more functions.  I am attempting to do this by encapsulating the coupled functions in a vector, and I would like to invoke the std::function wrapper in the process.  Below I am showing a simplified version of a similar code.  At present I am trying to define a way of encapsulating the functions in an array so that it can be passed to the `solver` function.  I am using a C++17 compiler with clang.  Is there a way to pass these functions in an array, or is there a better way to do this that I am not aware of?

```
double func1(std::map<std::string, double> arr)
{
    dydt = arr["one"] * 3.0 - arr["two"];
    return dydt;
}

double func2(std::map<std::string, double> arr)
{
    dydt = 1 / arr["three"] + 3.0 * arr["two"];
    return dydt;
}

double solver(std::vector<std::function<double(std::map<std::string, double>) &funcs, std::map<std::string, double> inputs)
{
    double res;
    std::vector<double> data;
    for (int i = 0; i < funcs.size(); i++)
    {
        // - The ODE solver is not shown in this example, 
        //   but it highlights the general intent
        res = funcs[i](inputs);
        data.push_back(res);
    }
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, double> inputs;
    inputs["one"] = 1.0;
    inputs["two"] = 2.0;
    inputs["three"] = 3.0;
    inputs["four"] = 4.0;

    // The line of code below does not work
    std::vector<std::function<double(std::map<std::string, double>)>> funcs = {func1, func2};
    std::vector<double> dat;

    // - Due to the fact that the array of funcs does not work, 
    //  this function call also does not work
    dat = solver(funcs, inputs);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `std::function` takes a `std::map<char, double>` but the functions you try to put into it take a `std::map<std::string, double>`. There are a number of other typographical errors that the compiler will tell you about. Once I fixed those typographical errors, the code compiled.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, you are correct, I just edited the example to replace the char with  std::string; however, it still does not work.  I get a message that states, `no mathing constructor`.

Comment: [Works for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PpqHNx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question as C++17, you can use a variadic function template with a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template<typename ...Funcs>
std::vector<double> solver(const std::map<std::string, double>& inputs, Funcs&&... funcs)
{
    std::vector<double> results;
    (results.push_back(funcs(inputs)), ...);
    return results;
}
```

I changed the argument type to `const std::map<std::string, double>&` for performance reasons. Passing by reference (`&`) is recommended here. Passing by value would copy the `std::map` on every function call. So the functions should be declared as:

```
double func1(const std::map<std::string, double>& arr);
```

Now you don't need a vector anymore to pass the functions. You can just pass them directly as arguments to `solver`:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, double> inputs {
        {"one", 1.0},
        {"two", 2.0},
        {"three", 3.0},
        {"four", 4.0}
    };

    auto results = solver(inputs, func1, func2);
}
```

Note that the `solver` function template accepts any callable. Lambdas for example also work:

```
solver(inputs,
    [](auto arr){ return arr["one"] * 3.0 - arr["two"]; },
    [](auto arr){ return 1 / arr["three"] + 3.0 * arr["two"]; }
);
```

(You can use `const std::map<std::string, double>& arr` instead of `auto arr` if that's more readable to you. Note that `auto` in a lambda means the lambda becomes a template.)

Comment: Hopefully I can get a chance to implement this tonight.  If it works for my needs, I will let you know.  Regardless, I have certainly learned something from your response, so I appreciate it.  The one very minor change I see is that I cannot make the map constant, as some of those variables will be updated at each time step of the ODE solver.

Comment: Your response answered my question as asked so I am going to mark this as the answer.  However, I did not ask the right question, so it did not answer my real question.  I will re-post; however, in general, is there a way to parse out each function from the fold expression.  I need to iterate through each function in a loop, and pass each individual function to another function where it will modify the values of `inputs` before the next function uses the `inputs` map.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using a mix of `std::function`, `std::any` and parameter pack:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <any>
#include <vector>

using my_f_type = std::function<int(std::map<std::string, int>&)>;

template<typename...T>
int solver(const T& ... functions) {
    std::vector<std::any> vec = { functions... };
    std::map<std::string, int> foo = { { "test", 37 } };
    for (auto& f : vec) {
        try {
            return std::any_cast<my_f_type>(f)(foo);
        } catch (const std::bad_any_cast& e) {}
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::function<int(int)> a = [](int a) { return a; };
    std::function<double(double)> b = [](double b) {return b; };
    my_f_type c = [](std::map<std::string, int>& c) { return c["test"]; };
    return solver(a, b, c);
}
```

In `main`, you have your list of functions to pass to `solver` that accepts n args. Then, the functions you passed are stored in a `std::vector` of `std::any`s. The try catch in this example e just a case of use, here I just want to call the `c` function. The return of `main` is 37.

I wanted to show here different types of functions. But if your functions are always of the same type, you can discard using `std::any` (and now passing `foo`):

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

template<typename...T>
int solver(std::map<std::string, int>& foo, const T& ... functions) {
    return (functions(foo) + ...);
}

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, int> foo = { { "a",1 },{ "b",2 },{ "c",3 } };
    auto a = [](std::map<std::string, int>& a) { return a["a"]; };
    auto b = [](std::map<std::string, int>& b) { return b["b"]; };
    auto c = [](std::map<std::string, int>& c) { return c["c"]; };
    solver(foo, a, b, c); // returns 6
}
```